# read only files in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, filesystem-corruption

Something has gone weird with Ubuntu 8.4 on my computer.  Somehow, many files, docs and audio have decided to become "read only". Other files (that I own) are denying permission to view, move copy or otherwise access.

Does anyone know how this could suddenly happen?

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to return these files to their original status?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a permissions issue. Open terminal and `cd` to one of the folders/files affected.

> sudo chown -R user:group ./folder
>
> sudo chmod -R 755 ./folder

- More info on setting permissions: [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)
- More information on setting ownership: [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)

Comment: of course "user" and "group" must be your actual username and groupname

Comment: Nice :)  But when I tried it, it needed to be sudo chmod 755 -R ./folder ---> not sure if that might be related to the flavor of linux I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Check for commonalities in the file locations.  Are they all on the same partition?  Only in a few subdirectories?

- If all affected files are under one (or a small number of) directory(ies), it may be a permissions problem.  [ricbax's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/79601/read-only-files-in-ubuntu/79606#79606) gives details to fix the issue, but use `ls -l` to verify that's the problem first.
- Ubuntu and other linuxes are often configured to remount the system partition as **read-only** when errors are detected.  If this is the case, `chown` and `chmod` won't help -- you'll need to fix the filesystem (eg with `fsck`) before you'll be able to remount the partition normally.  Any partition could potentially be mounted with this option.